# Make an API endpoint private

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express, passport.js

I'm developing a little webApp with AngularJS, express, nodejs and Passportjs. I have been creating endpoints on my API on demand but now I have a problem.
I have an endpoint which cannot be called by the users when they want. This API call is made when a user make an specific action in the app, so they earn points.
The endpoint is something like /api/users/updatePoints and I don't want the users with the developers tools resending the call and earning points they don't deserve.
How could I accomplish this? I have been thinking for a day but I can't think of anything reasonable.

Thank you in advance :)

--EDIT--
At last I have just deleted that ENDPOINT and write directly in the database in server-side. Not the solution I wanted but good enough. Thank you!!

Comment: Why don't you set up a flag when the user make that specific action in the app and check that flag when the updatePoints route is called?

Comment: That could make it. How could access a var from the index.js of my /api/users that has been set in the front-end? I could check it here: "router.post('/updatePoints', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.updatePoints);"

Comment: You can provide query parameters or data with your post operation.

Comment: @Trendy the problem of that approach is that you can reproduce it everytime you want, because this is in the front-end. So a user could catch the post to the API and send it all the times he wants and earn all the points he want. Thank you!

Comment: this is what i do not like with SPAs, API calls are exposed no matter what. agree with Jorge, putting the update points endpoint in the server side instead is the best approach for this manner. anyways i still prefer MVC over SPA, jquery works well so you do not have to submit and reload pages should you want it to

Answer (score 2):

It's already too late to answer but I think this could help someone.

To Privatize an endpoint, Allow only your whitelisted Origins by setting the respective response headers and for all other users send a 403 status code (Which implies forbidden, 401 says try again).

Here is an example of middleware that privatizes endpoints.

```
module.exports = function (allowedOrigins) {
   const whitelistedOrigins = Array.isArray(allowedOrigins) ? allowedOrigins : [allowedOrigins];
   return function (req, res, next) {
      const origin = req.headers.origin;
      if (whitelistedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
         res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
         next();
      } else {
         res.status(403).json({
           msg: "This is a private Endpoint, Please contact the Admin",
         });
      }
   };
};
```

Here is an example of usage.

```
const privatizeEndpoint = require("../customMiddlewares/privatizeEndpoint");

router.post("/someEndpoint", privatizeEndpoint(["http://myprivate.domain.com"]), (req, res) => {
     console.log("Inside Private Endpoint");
});
```

However, your endpoint will be still exposed but at least it will be served only to your whitelisted domains.

Notice that even requests without origin will be blocked (curl commands or through POSTMAN).